# Не выполняется код HTML в JS

Tags: javascript, html, php, mysql

Сперва передаю массив из php с помощью

```
$row['text'] = <img src="http://ajaxs.ru/demo/js/smail/smail/sleep.png">;//из базы данных
$msg[] = array("msg"=>htmlspecialchars($row['text']));
echo json_encode($msg);
```

Затем принимаю массив.
Вот код Javascript:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(msg_j);
for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i ++){
$('#chatIn').append(obj[i].msg);
}
```

Выводит: `<img src="http://ajaxs.ru/demo/js/smail/smail/sleep.png">`

А нужно чтобы выводил картинку, а не HTML код.

Comment: а что такое, извиняюсь, i у вас здесь ? цикл то где ?

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(msg_j);
for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i ++){
$('#chatIn').append(obj[i].msg);
}

Answer (score 1):

Правильный JS обработчик:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(msg_j);
for(var i=0; i < obj.length; i ++){
    var msg = htmlspecialchars_decode(obj[i].msg)
    $('#chatIn').html(msg);
}
```

Функцию "htmlspecialchars_decode" смотреть [тут](http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlspecialchars_decode/)

Comment: Потому и плохо хранить в БД HTML код...

Comment: Если ввести так var msg = htmlspecialchars_decode(obj[i].msg);
то все равно пустые строки.

Comment: Если так var msg = htmlspecialchars_decode(obj[i].msg());
То вообще ничего.

Comment: Суть в том, что вы экранируете HTML функцией "htmlspecialchars" перед конвертированием его в JSON. В таком виде принимаете текст JavaScript обработчиком и выводите экранированный HTML.
Как вариант можно передавать неэкранированный HTML, но Я никогда подобное не делал и не знаю получиться ли. И вообще это плохое решение, забудьте.

Comment: "obj[i].msg()" не пишите, это моя опечатка. Нуна "obj[i].msg"

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблему решил, брал исходник с сайта и css не посмотрел, а там 
<pre>
#chatIn img{
 display:block;
 visibility:hidden;
}
</pre>
:D

Answer (score 0):

Используйте jQuery метод html, что бы добавить. Например:

```
$('#chatIn').html(obj[i].msg);
```

Comment: Уже пробовал все равно тоже самое

Comment: @Линар Мухтаров http://jsfiddle.net/Lh5hm/ тут работает

Comment: да оно и так работает :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Lh5hm/1/

Comment: Так то работает я подставлял, но после парсинга какая то фигня происходит вроде все должно работать, но нет(

Comment: Нужно обработать HTML, полученный из БД, функцией htmlspecialchars_decode

Comment: Сделал теперь выводит просто пустые строки

Comment: Не там Вы сделали, смотрите мой ответ.